# Добавление Bitmap в ImageView

Tags: android, list, imagemagick

Пытаюсь добавить картинку из интернета в Bitmap в ImageView который находиться в SimpleAdapter. Вот код:

```
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
        threads = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> hm;
        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(TNAME, "Привет,");
        hm.put(TTEXT, "\"ХэшКод\"!");
        hm.put(IMG, ImageManager.downloadImage("http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png"));

        threads.add(hm);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, 
threads, R.layout.list, new String[]{TNAME,TTEXT,IMG}, new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2,R.id.img});
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Метод downloadImage:

```
 public static Bitmap downloadImage(String iUrl) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedInputStream buf_stream = null;
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting loading image by URL: " + iUrl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(iUrl).openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.connect();
            buf_stream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), 8192);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf_stream);
            buf_stream.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            buf_stream = null;
            conn = null;
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Url parsing was failed: " + iUrl);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, iUrl + " does not exists");
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Out of memory!!!");
            return null;
        } finally {
            if ( buf_stream != null )
                try { buf_stream.close(); } catch (IOException ex) {}
            if ( conn != null )
                conn.disconnect();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Всё работает, но изображение не появляется, в logcat при этом пишется, "resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@*NUMBER*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны добавлять в `HashMap` с ключом `IMG` не `Bitmap`, а путь к нему.

Допустим, локальный файл:

```
// выбираем для скачивания папку Download
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS); 
File file = new File(dir, name); 
if (!file.exists()) { 
  try { 
    if (!file.createNewFile()) { return; } 
  } catch (IOException e) { 
  } 
}
```

Далее создаете output-поток и пишете в него

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file); 
// byteArray - то, что пришло из input-потока
os.write(byteArray); 
os.flush(); 
os.close();
```

А в map добавляете `file.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, но как это, можете объяснить?

Comment: Не знаю, можно ли прописать просто путь до удаленного файла (`http://`), но если нет, то стоит сначала скачивать файл.

Comment: А я что делаю?

Comment: Вы держите в памяти контент удаленного файла и его же добавляете в map.

Comment: Спасибо, но есть метод попроще?

Comment: Можете создать кастомный вид для элементов, переопределив метод `getView` у вашего `ArrayAdapter`. Но для начала убедитесь, что действительно нельзя просто добавить в map удаленный адрес (`http://`), этого я не проверял.

Comment: Нет добавление адреса не работает.
Вот что пишет:    "resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png"